# Any way to speed up cardano-node startup?

Tags: cardano-node

cardano-node is now taking around 50 minutes to start on my hardware, I dont do it often but its quite slow.  I think the issue is the process where it replays all the block chunks.

That seems to be pretty much a single threaded process, is there any way to parallelize it with more CPU cores?

Systemd service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Cardano Node for mainnet
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/home/cardano/.local/bin/cardano-node run --database-path /home/cardano/cnode/db --socket-path /home/cardano/cnode/sockets/node.socket --port 3001 --config /home/cardano/cnode/config/mainnet-config.json  --topology /home/cardano/cnode/config/mainnet-topology.json
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=60
User=cardano

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your node is starting slow because it was not stopped normally.
You can add more CPU Cores to the process, but this will still not start the cardano-node quick when it is stopped abnormally. But you can still make it start fast in this case by creating an empty file with the name "clean" in the db folder, while it is stopped, and then start it.

If you can post the systemd service file you use for the cardano-node service definition, I can tell you what to change so that the service is stopped normally.

EDIT: I updated your service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Cardano Node for mainnet
After=network.target

[Service]
User=cardano
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/home/cardano/.local/bin/cardano-node run +RTS -N -RTS --database-path /home/cardano/cnode/db --socket-path /home/cardano/cnode/sockets/node.socket --port 3001 --config /home/cardano/cnode/config/mainnet-config.json  --topology /home/cardano/cnode/config/mainnet-topology.json
Restart=on-failure
KillSignal= SIGINT
TimeoutStopSec=300
LimitNOFILE=32768
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Thanks, I have asked about cleanly shutting down cardano-node before and never really got a good answer, question edited to include systemd file.  Also if more cores can be added, that would also be good, how can I do that please?

Comment: I edited my post with the required modifications to your service file.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt want the RTS flags but the other parts were useful

Answer (score 0):

Hey George,

Initially, I got a sync error, so I deleted the files in 'chain' and 'wallets' from appdata Daedalus Mainnet folder and did a full resync. The issue is that it's been more than 24 hrs and it's at 78% synced.

Is there a way to speed up the Daedalus Mainnet sync process?

Thank you,
Florin